# How to do arithmetic on tidy data in pandas?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` in "[tidy](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf)" format (columns are variables, rows are observations) containing time series data for several different conditions. I'd like to normalize the data to the zero-hour time point for each condition.

For example, lets say I fed two different `animal`s two different kinds of `meal`, then every hour I recorded how much food was left:

```
In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
   animal       meal  time  food_left
0    lion       meat     0         10
1    lion       meat     1          5
2    lion       meat     2          2
3   tiger       meat     0          5
4   tiger       meat     1          3
5   tiger       meat     2          2
6    lion  vegetable     0          5
7    lion  vegetable     1          5
8    lion  vegetable     2          5
9   tiger  vegetable     0          5
10  tiger  vegetable     1          5
11  tiger  vegetable     2          5
```

For each `time` point, I want to calculate how much food a particular animal has eaten (`food_eaten`) by subtracting `food_left` at that time point from `food_left` at time point zero (for that animal and meal), then store the result in another column, e.g.:

```
   animal       meal  time  food_left  food_eaten
0    lion       meat     0         10           0
1    lion       meat     1          5           5
2    lion       meat     2          2           8
3   tiger       meat     0          5           0
4   tiger       meat     1          3           2
5   tiger       meat     2          2           3
6    lion  vegetable     0          5           0
7    lion  vegetable     1          5           0
8    lion  vegetable     2          5           0
9   tiger  vegetable     0          5           0
10  tiger  vegetable     1          5           0
11  tiger  vegetable     2          5           0
```

I'm struggling to figure out how to apply this transformation in Pandas to produce the final data frame (preferably also in tidy format). Importantly, I need to keep the metadata (`animal`, `meal`, etc.).

Preferably I'd like a solution which generalizes to different groupings and transformations; for instance, what if I want to divide the amount the tiger ate at each time point by the amount the lion ate (for a given meal) at that time point, or find out how much less the lion ate of vegetables than meat, and so on.

---

Things I've tried:

- `groupby`:

  ```
  In [15]: df2 = df.set_index(['time'])
  In [16]: df2.groupby(['animal','meal']).transform(lambda x: x[0] - x)
  Out[16]: 
        food_left
  time           
  0             0
  1             5
  2             8
  0             0
  1             2
  2             3
  0             0
  1             0
  2             0
  0             0
  1             0
  2             0
  ```

  Result is correct, but the metadata is lost, and I can't join it back to the original `df`
- If I `set_index` on `['time', 'animal', 'meal']`, then I can't `groupby`:

  ```
  In [17]: df2 = df.set_index(['time','animal','meal'])
  In [19]: df2.groupby(['animal','meal']).transform(lambda x: x[0] - x)
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)

  ... snip ...

  KeyError: 'animal'
  ```
- `pivot`:

  ```
  In [21]: data_pivot = df.pivot_table(columns=['animal','meal'],index=['time'],values='food_left')

  In [22]: data_norm = data_pivot.rsub(data_pivot.loc[0], axis=1)

  In [23]: data_norm
  Out[23]: 
  animal lion           tiger          
  meal   meat vegetable  meat vegetable
  time                                 
  0         0         0     0         0
  1         5         0     2         0
  2         8         0     3         0
  ```

  This is a bit better and I could probably retrieve the original data with `melt` or `unstack`, but it seems inelegant. Is there a better way?

Comment: How about assigning the column you calculated back to the data frame as `df2['food_eaten'] = df2.groupby(['animal','meal']).transform(lambda x: x[0] - x)`?

Comment: Hm, that seems like a good solution; is `transform` guaranteed to give back elements in the same order as input (I see it's guaranteed to be in the same shape)? If you post this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I believe so. According to the documentation, `The transform method returns an object that is indexed the same (same size) as the one being grouped.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new column based on the transformed data, as a one-liner, it would be:

```
df['food_eaten'] = df.set_index(['time']).groupby(['animal', 'meal']).
                      transform(lambda x: x[0] - x).values
```

df

```
    animal  meal    time    food_left   food_eaten
0   lion    meat       0          10             0
1   lion    meat       1          5              5
2   lion    meat       2          2              8
3   tiger   meat       0          5              0
4   tiger   meat       1          3              2
5   tiger   meat       2          2              3
6   lion    vegetable  0          5              0
7   lion    vegetable  1          5              0
8   lion    vegetable  2          5              0
9   tiger   vegetable  0          5              0
10  tiger   vegetable  1          5              0
11  tiger   vegetable  2          5              0
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `groupby` and `diff`:

```
df['food_eaten'] = -df.groupby(['animal', 'meal'])['food_left'].diff()
```

Follow that with fillna() if you want zeroes rather than NaN for situations where nothing was eaten. While this doesn't directly generalize you now have the amount of food of each type eaten by each animal in each time interval, so you can do the additional computations on this new field.

Comment: If you look at the example, this doesn't actually produce the correct output which was to subtract the zero time point (rather than take the finite difference between each two elements). This can be made correct by using `cumsum` (like taking the derivative then integrating) but that requires a second `groupby`; interesting solution, but doesn't really generalize to other operations.